# Не работает код, при добавлении классов в исходный код

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет, в jQuery и JS я ещё новичок и столкнулся с проблемой.
Есть код, который при клике на `checkbox` добавляет код в блок:

```
$('input[name="mods[]"]').click(function(){ 
var mid = $(this).data('id');
    if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
        $('.modal-box-list-'+ mid).remove();
        $('.modal-list-mods').append('<div class="modal-box-list-'+ mid +'"><div class="modal-box-list" data-lid="'+ mid +'"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" class="modal-input-list" checked="checked"><span></span>'+ $(this).data('name') +'</label></div></div>');
    }
    if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
        $('.modal-box-list-'+ mid).remove();
    }   
});
```

Мне нужно сделать чтобы при клике в данном блоке на `checkbox` снимался бы "главный" `checkbox` (тот который добавляет код в блок), но:

```
$('.modal-box-list').click(function(){
    alert('ok');
});
```

Уже не работает, вероятно из-за того что при загрузке в исходной странице данный блока не было.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jquery.on()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/On) - вам поможет данный метод в решении вашей проблемы

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы расширить принятый ответ до более понятного, следует указать, что наилучший способ решить Вашу проблему -- это использовать так называемые делегированные события (delegated events). Работает это следующим образом.

jQuery имеет универсальный метод [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/), с помощью которого можно назначить событие `click` для любого **статического** родителя требуемого *динамического* элемента (селектор для него указывается вторым параметром функции). По умолчанию, при клике на любой объект в DOM дереве, браузер пытается найти среди родителей этого элемента все, которые имеют установленные замыкания на конкретное событие (в нашем случае `click`) и вызывает эти события. Метод `on` в режиме *"делегирования"* проверит попадает ли реально вызвавший событие потомок под заданный вторым параметром селектор. Если попадает -- вызывает замыкание на событие, если нет, то пропускает.

В Вашем случае требуется назначить событие `click` для ближайшего статически созданного (существующего на момент установки события) элемента в дереве элементов. Полагаю, что такими родителями могут являться элементы с классом `modal-list-mods`. Отсюда, искомый код будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
$('.modal-list-mods').on('click', '.modal-box-list', function() {
    console.log('произведен клик на элементе с классом "modal-box-list"');
});
```

Подробное описание метода доступно в [документации к jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)<sup>[en]</sup>.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно повторно привязать обработчик события для нового элемента (после добавляения)